# SwiftUI - Detect taps in a disabled SecureField?

Tags: ios, swiftui, textfield, securefield

I am writing an iOS app using SwiftUI.  As part of the data presented, I need to have a password field with a show/hide button that toggles between hidden/visible.  To do this, I'm using a combination of SwiftUI's `SecureField` and `TextField` controls.  Both are in the `disabled` state to prevent users from editing, as I want this field to be read-only.  This setup is working perfectly.  (See screenshot below)

[image]

Now I would like to add functionality that would allow the user to copy the password to the clipboard just by tapping on it.  I've added an `onTapGesture` block to my `SecureField`, however it is never called.  I believe this is due to the fact that my `SecureField`/`TextField` is marked as disabled.  A snippet of my code follows:

```
        ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            if isSecured {
                VStack {
                    SecureField("", text: Binding.constant(text))
                        .disabled(true)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            print("USER TAPPED!")
                        }
                }
            } else {
                TextField("", text: Binding.constant(text))
                    .disabled(true)
            }
            
            Image(systemName: self.isSecured ? "eye" : "eye.slash")
                .accentColor(.gray)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                .modifier(TouchDownUpEventModifier(changeState: { (buttonState) in
                    
                    withAnimation {
                        self.isSecured.toggle()
                    }
                }))
        }
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?  I want my `SecureField`/`TextField` to be read-only but still detect when a user taps the control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding the following modifiers on my `ZStack`:

```
.contentShape(Rectangle())
.onTapGesture {
   ...
}
```

Once I did this, my `ZStack` began intercepting the touch events and I could perform the desired action.